# Not receiving redirect URL from instagram

Tags: c#, oauth, instagram-api

I'm new to OAuth, and I'm trying to write a method to get an access code for Instagram using OAuth authentication (Detailed [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/)).

However, the response uri in my method keeps returning the same URL that it was created with, instead of the URL containing the access token that I need.

My method looks like this:

```
    private string getRedirectURL(string URL)
    {
        string redirectURL = null;

        try
        {
            instaRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            instaRequest.Timeout = 1000;

            HttpWebResponse instaResponse = (HttpWebResponse)instaRequest.GetResponse();

            using (instaResponse)
            {
                if (instaResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    return redirectURL =  instaResponse.ResponseUri.ToString();
                }
            }

            return redirectURL;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return redirectURL;
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?